# SendMessage vs. WndProc

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I'm trying to extend `TextBox` control to add watermarking functionality. The example I've found on CodeProject is using imported SendMessage function.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

void SetWatermark()
{
    SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x1501, 0, "Sample");
}
```

I'm wondering why not use protected WndProc instead

```
void SetWatermark()
{
    var m =new Message() { HWnd = this.Handle, Msg = 0x1501, WParam = (IntPtr)0, LParam = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Sample") };
    WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Both seem to work fine. Almost all examples I've seen on internet use `SendMessage`function. Why is that? Isn't `WndProc` function designed to replace `SendMessage`?

P.S. I don't know right to convert `string` to `IntPtr` and found that `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` works ok. Is it right function to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) does not replace `SendMessage`, it is the .NET equivalent of [`WindowProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573(VS.85).aspx). `WndProc` is called by your application's message pump (which receives messages that are sent or posted by `SendMessage` or `PostMessage`) to process them. By calling `WndProc` directly, you by-pass the special message handling that Windows performs, such as bundling `WM_PAINT` messages, and can potentially cause some nasty problems where messages appear out of the order that they're expected by windows within your application.

As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx),

> All messages are sent to the WndProc
>   method after getting filtered through
>   the PreProcessMessage method.
>
> The WndProc method corresponds exactly
>   to the Windows WindowProc function.
>   For more information about processing
>   Windows messages, see the WindowProc
>   function documentation in the MSDN
>   library at
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library.

By calling it directly, you deprive the system of a chance to perform preprocessing or any other handling of that message. The .NET framework runs on top of Windows and without sending or posting the message, the underlying system cannot do anything with that message, so you lose out on anything the underlying system might do for you.